# Regex with limiting quantifier does not work in g++ (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, regex, g++

I have to use POSIX's `regex.h` for some reason in Ubuntu 14.04 g++(version 4.8.4)
However it seems that regex does not work in this environment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex_t regex;

    int result = regcomp(&regex, "RESERVE [A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]* [0-9]{7}", 0);    
    if(result){
        cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
    }


    result = regexec(&regex, "RESERVE MrKim 1111111", 0, NULL, 0);
    if(!result){
        cout<<"MATCH"<<endl;
    }
    else if(result == REG_NOMATCH){
        cout<<"NO MATCH"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        char msg[100];
        regerror(result, &regex, msg, 100);
        cout<<msg<<endl;
    }

}
```

Above program only prints "NO MATCH"...
Please give me a advice.

Comment: Use [`REG_EXTENDED`](https://ideone.com/x8vW6H).

Comment: No, I doubt it is that duplicate, it is not C++, but C.

Comment: This is cpp code but I can't use c++11 standard library `<regex>` because of compatibility.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you . It works well.

Comment: @stribizhev: Post that as an answer and perhaps describe why it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have here is that your regex is written in POSIX ERE style (the limiting quantifier is written as `{7}`).

To make sure your regex works, you need ERE regex type that can be enabled with the `REG_EXTENDED` flag.

The BRE regex type supports limiting quantifiers (you have one in your regex `{7}`), but you need to escape them: `\{7\}`.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/x8vW6H) and more details about POSIX BRE/ERE distinctions at [*POSIX Basic Regular Expressions*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

Comment: Same thing is with round brackets, in BRE, they need to be escaped in order to define a grouping. Unescape round brackets match literal parentheses in BRE regex.